# Find the function is Even,odd none

Tags: integration

We have to find the value of $$ f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \log\left(\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right) \, dx. $$

So here I put $f(-x)$ and tried to solve the integration but seems lengthy because I consider it $(1, \log x)$ and then solve it. The question is asked in a teaching exam means there is maybe a short/direct solution. Help regarding this.

Comment: If the function is neither even nor odd , you should quickly find some real number $x$ for which $f(-x)$ is neither $f(x)$ nor $-f(x)$.

Comment: I hope this is the desired function. I interpreted it as the logarithm of the numerator , and this divided by the denominator.

Comment: If it matters at all, a known identity is 
$$
\text{artanh}(x) = \frac 1 2 \ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right), \; |x|<1
$$

Comment: I don't know how arctan works for identity function even odd by the way thank you for a nice edit

Comment: $x$ is playing two different roles here. That is very bad form!

Comment: Even function derviatve is odd any idea?

Comment: We should use $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \log\left(\frac{1+\sin t}{1-\sin t}\right) \, dt$$

Comment: But how to solve it?

Comment: Can we not use sum of trigonometry series formula?

Comment: you could take the derivative on both sides to see if it is odd or even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us show that the function is symmteric.

Let

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \log \left(\frac{1+\sin (t)}{1-\sin (t)}\right) \, dt$$

and consider

$$f(-x) = \int_0^{-x} \log \left(\frac{1+\sin (t)}{1-\sin (t)}\right) \, dt$$

The substitution $t\to-u, dt\to-du$ gives

$$f(-x) = -\int_0^{x} \log \left(\frac{1+\sin (-u)}{1-\sin (-u)}\right) \, du\\=\int_0^{x} \log \left(\frac{1+\sin (u)}{1-\sin (u)}\right) \, du\\
= f(x)$$

QED.

Comment: I checked it by integration the integration is odd. Not even please look at it and tell me any short trick

Comment: @ nawal arjun An even function has an odd derivative, but an odd derivative is not sufficient in general for a function to be even.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example why is not sufficient for odd derivative? And in this integration is even so function is surely odd right?

Comment: @ nawal arjun Ok, integrating $f'(-x) = -f'(x)$ gives $f(-x) = -f(x) + const$, and the constant spoils the symmetry. But honestly, I would greatly appreciate some work on this problem from your side.

Comment: $X^2$ is even and this derivative 2x is odd